# In Firefox, use a plugin or extension to invoke "unsafe" APIs?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, plugins, xul

Firefox extensions can invoke privileged APIs (e.g. nsIProcess to start an external app) without bugging the user, for example this extension does it from the download window: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10902/

I need to do the same kind of thing, but from a UI on a web page. Can an extension provide a XUL widget (which calls the privileged APIs via a component module) that I can instantiate in the page DOM? Or do I need to write a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

As that page says, there are security risks involved with this, so be careful.

Comment: @sdwilsh: What do you mean it will prompt the user? I've been using the technique described on that page, firing a custom event from a webpage and listening for it from the privileged code in my extension, without any user prompts. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: My bad - looked at the wrong tab that still managed to have context to this question I guess (enablePrivledge).  This answer is in fact the right way to do this!

Comment: That's indeed what I needed to know! And here's the extension I've built: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/240637/